# Splitting and transcoding Mpeg-2 in Java

Tags: java, video-processing, mpeg-2

I want to try to implement parallel (by parts) transcoding of the Mpeg-2 into a sequence of images (jpg/png etc).
As far as I see I need to do two steps:

- Split video into N binary parts
- Transcode each of them into image.

I don't clearly understand how to do these steps correctly. What should I be looking for when I'll start splitting (header/body/GOP/some kind of offset/etc)?
Are there any libs (`JCodec, JavaCV, old Xuggler`?) that can help me or should I do both steps manually?
I would be very thankful for your advices.

**updated** (removed offtopic questions)

Comment: Please don't post multiple questions at once. 1) _Analyze input file and it’s structure. What should I be looking for?_ - this __far__ to broad question for SO, 2) _Split it into binary(?) parts to be able to transcode each one independently._ - this most likely answerable but at least show some research effort :) 3) _Transcode each binary part. Are there any libs that are able to do this task?_ - recommendations are off-topic on SO.

Comment: I disagree with you in some points. You are right about choosing the structure, so let's say that it is mpeg-2. But to do the further steps (also they are depending one from other) I need your advice about how to start splitting it (header/body/equal parts/etc). Will I have to do all manually or are there any libs that can do the part of the stuff (recommendations - yes). I don't ask you to give me the working code. I need to know what are the main steps to reach the goal.

Comment: Hey, I didn't downvote, did I? :) Seriously though there is a very small chance you'll get an answer for this question. [tag:apache-spark] attracts rather small group of users. Not to mention there is nothing really Spark specific here. I would really recommend asking separate questions with a proper tagging.

Comment: I agree that there is nothing about spark here. Just mentioned about it to show the full picture about what I want to do. I can modify my question and remove spark and other off-topic things if it helps.

Comment: I it is your question. Regarding Spark I would keep in mind that processing large binary files is far from obvious so some initial processing (like splitting file per frame) can a good idea especially if you have limited amount of RAM. Take care.